# Use "sed" to replace file containing "" and \

Tags: sed, escape-characters

I have a JSON file that looks like:

```
{
...
"python.pythonPath": "",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "",
...
}
```

I want to update it to

```
{
...
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxxx9/bin/python",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxxx9/bin/python",
...
}
```

I am confused about using escape characters **/** and single and double quotation marks. How do I do this using sed?

FYI. I am using macOS
I tried :

```
sed -i "" 's|/"/"|/"/Users/user//.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxxx9/bin/python/"' settings.json
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to parse json with commands not meant to do this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/11503700) on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get the sed command working. I however found a way to run a Python script inside bash that did the job for me.
If anyone is interested:

```
export new_path="/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxx9/bin/python"

python3 - << EOF
import json
import os

with open('settings.json', mode='r+') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data['python.defaultInterpreterPath'] = os.environ['new_path']
    data['python.pythonPath'] = os.environ['new_path']    
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    file.truncate()
EOF
echo 'continue bash'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be doing the trick as similarly as what you've already tried but not recommended to edit json files this way it's better to use `jq` as already been suggested.

```
sed -i 's/""/"\/Users\/user\/.local\/share\/virtualenvs\/venv-Qxxxxxx9\/bin\/python"/g' settings.json
```

The output should be as follows;

```
{
...
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxxx9/bin/python",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxxx9/bin/python".
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I want to use sed is because this step is a part of a larger script. I could have done the same with Python, rather than jq that I am not familiar with.
The proposed command does not however work, I get an error 
sed: 1: "settings.json": unterminated substitute pattern

Comment: Better to choose another delimiter for sed substitution command, such as `|`, so that you do not need to escape so many slashes.

Comment: This will change all occurrences of `""`, not only the ones specified in the question.

Comment: Hi @Karthik I've already tried it with sample data as given in question, it doesn't throws any error though. However, I'm running this in bash in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @terdon yes I've given solution specific to `""` thought that's what OP might have requested for. In any case he didn't I'll change the solution as accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Skynet for looking into the issue. I'm running the script on macOS and it requires an additional `""` after the `-i`.

Comment: @Karthik thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in `awk` instead, which makes it easier to only apply the substitution if the value is `""` *and* the key is one of the two desired ones:

```
$ awk -F: -vOFS=" : " '
    $1=="\"python.pythonPath\"" || 
    $1=="\"python.defaultInterpreterPath\""{
            $2="\"/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxx9/bin/python\","}
    1;
' file 
{
...
"python.pythonPath" "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxx9/bin/python"
"python.defaultInterpreterPath" "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-Qxxxxx9/bin/python"
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @terdon.